# Python - Increase speed of loading pre-trained model

Tags: python, model

I am working with word2vec. I have to load model (GoogleNews vector). But each time run project, It wastes a lot of time to load the model (about 3-4 min). Is there any way to load faster?
Below is my code to load model:

```
print("Loading the model file...")
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('~/Downloads/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)
print("Successfully loaded GoogleNews bin file!")
```

Comment: GoogleNews word2vec is about 1.5GB if I remember correctly. I think 3-4 minute to load such a huge file is okay.

Comment: I think you can use the 100 size vector without any appreciable loss in accuracy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to speed up Gensim Word2vec model load time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986405/how-to-speed-up-gensim-word2vec-model-load-time)

Comment: Yeah, But I am searching a solution that can "cache" it after the first loading time