# Shared memory among processes for pre-trained word2vec model?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, word2vec

I have a look-up object, specifically a pre-trained word2vec model from `gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors`. I need to do some data pre-processing and I am using multi-processing for the same. Is there a way in which all of my processes can use the object from the same memory location instead of each process loading the object into its own memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if:

- the files were saved using Gensim's internal `.save()` method, and the relevant large-arrays of vectors are clearly separate `.npy` files
- the files are loaded using Gensim's internal `.load()` method, with the `mmap` option
- you avoid doing any operations which inadvertently cause each process's object to reallocate the backing array completely (breaking the mmap-sharing).

See [this prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43067907/130288) for an overview of the steps/concerns of a similar need.

(The concern & extra steps listed there to avoid breaking the mmap-sharing – by performing manual patch-ups of the `norm` properties – should no longer be necessary in Gensim 4.0.0, currently available only as a prerelease version.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here are two options:

- you can use [multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10724332/1453508)
- or you can use [Ray](https://ray.io/)