# Use fasttext model (gensim) with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, gensim, fasttext

Is it possible to access a fasttext model (gensim) using multithreading?
Currently, I'm trying to load a model once (due to size and loading time), so it stays in memory and access its similarity functions multiple thousands times in a row. I want to do that in parallel and my current approach uses a wrapper class that loads the model and is then passed to the workers. But it looks like it does not return any results.

The wrapper class. Initiated once.

```py
from gensim.models.fasttext import load_facebook_model

class FastTextLocalModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model_name = "cc.de.300.bin"
        self.model_path = path.join("data", "models", self.model_name)
        self.fast_text = None

    def load_model(self):
        self.fast_text = load_facebook_model(self.model_path)

    def similarity(self, word1: str = None, word2: str = None):
        return self.fast_text.wv.similarity(word1, word2)
```

And the Processor class makes use of the `FastTextLocalModel` methods above:

```py
fast_text_instance = FastTextLocalModel()
fast_text_instance.load_model()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as executor:
        docs = corpus.get_documents()  # docs is iterable
        processor = ProcessorClass(model=fast_text_instance)
        executor.map(processor.process, docs)
```

Using `max_workers=1` seems to work.
I have to mention that I have no expertise in python multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

There may be useful ideas for you in this prior answer, which may need adaptation for `FastText` & latest versions of `gensim`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43067907/130288

(The keys are...

- even redundantly loading in different processes may not use redundant memory, if the key memory-consuming arrays are `mmap`ped and thus automatically shared at the OS level; and
- you have to do a little extra trickery to prevent the usual recalc after-load and before-similarity-ops of normed vectors, which would destroy the sharing

..but messiness in the `FastText` code might make these a bit harder there.)