# Load trained model only once

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science, fasttext

I have a FastText trained model "*.ftz". My program runs in the multithread mode.

Is there anyway to load a model once and use it without loading for each thread?

Comment: Good question. There are ways to do that in Gensim's FastText support, with models saved in Gensim's (multi-file) format. The steps are similar to the process described at another answer about `Word2Vec` models – https://stackoverflow.com/a/43067907/130288 – but may be slightly different for `FastText` and in recent Gensim 4.0+ versions.

Answer (score 0):

After some efforts to find a good solution I used Fastapi and implemented model as a service.

Comment: Please include a code snippet of your solution for those encountering the same problem.