# Unable to Load FastText model

Tags: nlp, gensim, fasttext

I am trying to load the FastText and save that as a model so that I can deploy that on production as the file size is 1.2 gb and wont be a good practice to use that on Prod.
Can anyone suggest an approach to save and load the model for production ("fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300")
[Loading the file using gensim.downloader api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgACr.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library https://github.com/avidale/compress-fasttext, which is  a wrapper around Gensim that can serve compressed versions of unsupervised FastText models.
The compressed versions can be orders of magnitude smaller (e.g. 20mb), with a tolerable loss in quality.

Comment: Great library! If you're not already doing something similar, you might want to consider offering as an optional step the sort of postprocessing (mostly recentering) described in this 'All-But-The-Top' paper – https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01417 – which might synergize well with compression (maybe improving it, maybe offsetting the occasional compression-related dacy in evaluations).

Answer (score 0):

In order to have clarity over exactly what you're getting, in what format, I strongly recommend downloading things like sets of pretrained vectors from their original sources rather than the Gensim `gensim.downloader` convenience methods. (That API also, against most users' expectations & best packaging hygeine, will download & run arbitrary other code that's not part of Gensim's version-controlled source repository or its official PyPI package. See [project issue #2283](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2283).)

For example, you could grab the raw vectors files direct from: https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html

The tool from [~david-dale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71509847/130288) looks interesting, for its radical compression, and if you can verify the compressed versions still work well for your purposes, it may be an ideal approach for memory-limited production deployments.

I would also consider:

- A production machine with enough GB of RAM to load the full model may not be too costly, and with these sorts of vector-models, typical access patterns mean you essentially *always* want the full model in RAM, with no virtual-memory swapping at all. If your deployment is in a web server, there are some memory-mapping tricks possible that can help many processes share the same singly-loaded copy of the model (to avoid time- and memory-consumptive redundant reloads). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986405/how-to-speed-up-gensim-word2vec-model-load-time/43067907#43067907) for an approach that works with `Word2Vec` (though that may need some adaptation for `FastText` & recent Gensim versions).
- If you don't need the Fasttext-specific subword-based synthesis, you can save the full-word vectors to a file in a simple format, then choose to only reload any small subset of the leading vectors (most common words) using the `limit` option of `load_word2vec_format()`. For exmaple:

```
# save only the word-vectors from a FastText model
ft_model.wv.save_word2vec_format('wvonly.txt', binary=False)
# ... then, later/elsewhere:

# load only 1st 50,000 word-vectors
wordvecs = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('wvonly.txt', binary=False, limit=50000)
```